# This website is making a potentially unsafe request. We recommend you do not allow access

Tags: google-oauth

I have been receiving this warning
http://screencast.com/t/S6B00lMG0oC
on google oauth authorisation since yesterday.

Can it be somehow related to the fact that I use oauth version 1 implementation which is depreceted?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing that warning because nimble.com is using OAuth v1.0 (which is vulnerable to Session Fixation Attack, see [how it works](http://hueniverse.com/2009/04/explaining-the-oauth-session-fixation-attack/)). In order to avoid getting that warning I recommend you implement OAuth v1.0a as per [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref). Alternatively, you could implement OAuth2 as suggested by Chao Wei.

You also mentioned that you started seeing the warning yesterday, that feels wrong as a warning message for apps using (legacy) OAuth v1.0 has been shown for years in Google authorization pages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I'd suggest using OAuth 2.0 if possible.